# Android studio error! Simulador dispositivo físico

Tags: java, android, android-studio, flutter, gradle

Cuando intento ejecutar mi aplicación en un dispositivo físico, aparece este error y realmente no sé cómo solucionarlo, tengo todo bien instalado y es muy raro que esto aparezca.

por favor necesita ayuda para resolver este problema, muchas gracias!

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM A305G in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: services.gradle.org
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:666)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Application finished.
```

Comment: Hola. Esta es la versión en Español. Por favor, traduce tu pregunta! :)

Comment: Listo lo acabo de traducir, gracias por avisar. :D

Comment: Por favor no coloques urgente en tu título no hará que la ayuda llegue mas rápido

Comment: Hola! Unas consultas, solo sucede con tu esta aplicación? Es decir otras aplicaciones si se pueden instalar? Esta activado el modo debug en tu celular físico? 
Podrías agregar la version de tus sistema operativo de tu celular y tu archivo gradle para ayudarte :)

Comment: Ya lo logre solucionar por lo que vi solo era la falta de internet ya que al activar el internet nuevamente el simulador fisico me funciono sin ningun problema